# Export Event Stream data from Marketing Cloud Personalization into FTP location

Tags: marketing-cloud, website-integration

We have a requirement where we need to do Lead Scoring using website visitors tracking data.

We want to export this MC Personalization website tracking event streams with fields such as :

- EmailAddress
- ContactId/UserId
- Website URL
- Page Visited
- Visit Date/Event Date

Let me know if there any way get this data exported in an automated way to FTP location.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to export the Event Stream. An alternative way to achieve what you are after would be to leverage the Managed Package that connects MCP with SFCRM in a daily sync.